# Manipulate dataframe so that column sum is equal to constant

Tags: python

I got a dataframe with 1500 rows and 25 columns where each cell can take the value 0 or 1 with a maximum of three 1s per row:

ID, t01, t02, t03, t04, t05, .... t25

s0001, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,...., 1

s0002, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,..., 0

s0003, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...., 1

.

.

.

s1500, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,...., 0

Now I need to transform this dataframe, so that each row only contains a single 1 and the sum of the columns all add up to 60 (1500/25 =60 ; +/- 2 tolerance is fine), meaning that all 1s are distributed evenly among the columns. 
I tried solving this through using lists and assigning the IDs step by step to individual lists, however, this only leaves me with a bunch of unassigned IDs for the very last columns since I mainly used if and for loops to iterate over the single lists, not the entire data frame.

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE
As mentioned in the comment: In the end, two of the three 1s need to be deleted. The 1s contain basically preferences for the single columns that represent topics that have been chosen. So the idea is to assign each individual - represented by the ID - to a topic based on the preferences so that the groups that handle one topic are about the same size

Comment: If you have three `1`s per row, and you want one `1` per row, then what determines where that `1` goes in the result?

Comment: In the end, two of the three 1s need to be deleted. The 1s contain basically preferences for the single columns that represent topics that have been chosen. So the idea is to assign each individual - represented by the ID - to a topic based on the preferences so that the groups that handle one topic are about the same size

Comment: From the sounds of it, this is what you're looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: And for some unsolicited advice, which is offered with the friendliest of intentions: Please read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form